# How to pass in a model in a redirect request in django

Tags: python, django, web

I'm creating a login View in which soon after a user is authenticated I'm logging that user in by redirecting to 'dashboard' page but I also want to sent additional data about the user to the 'dashboard' page so that I can display it dynamically on the template. For this, I'm trying to send a model as a parameter in redirect but django is not displaying anything on the template.

```
    if user is not None:
        # authenticate the user
        auth.login(request, user)

        # Fetch additional information about the user
        # fetching presonal-Information
        try:
            personal_info = PersonalInformation.objects.get(user_id=user.id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            personal_info = None

        return redirect('dashboard',  personal_info)
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid credentials')
        return redirect('login')

else:
    return render(request, 'pages/login.html')
```

Comment: Why do you need to send this? Since you get it via the user object, why don't you do that in the dashboard view?

Comment: In the dashboard, you can simply fetch the relevant data. Note that you can not send the model itself. You can send the primary key, or somehow encode the model, but that will not make much difference.

Comment: In my PersonalInformation model i have a fk reference to User but not the other way around.Then how should i fetch the data.

Comment: As long as you declare reference with `ForeignField`, you can fetch it using [reverse reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: i tried reading about reverse reference but could not understand much so can you please describe it with the help of some codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using the user related data in dashboard template store all the user data in the session like this:

```
personal_info = PersonalInformation.objects.get(user_id=user.id)
request.session['user_id']=personal_info.user_id
request.session['user_name']=personal_info.user_name
```

and so on....

then use that session in your template to retrieve the data like this:

```
{{request.session.user_id}}
{{request.session.user_name}}
```

Comment: Do not store django models in sessions. Store their pk instead.

Comment: in template you can access logged in user via {{request.user}}  so to get pk inside template you can get it with {{request.user.pk}}  you don't need session and iterrate personal info via fk relationship.

Comment: It is true only when we use Django's User modal.

Comment: so basically the User model needs to have a foreign key reference to Personal Information model so as to fetch the data from it right?

Comment: you can do that using OneToOne relationship but my answer will work for you perfectly

Comment: please upvote and accept my answer if you are satisfied